# Collection View Loads Choppy

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection view that is loading data from an API. The Collection View works fine, except it only loads images on scroll. I've tried loading the images async and it makes a minimal difference. I want all the images to be loaded or have a preloading image until the image loads? I'm using Haneke to load images from a URL. Here's the code I'm using in my collection view:

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tableData.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: ProductsViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("productViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProductsViewCell

    let rowData = tableData[indexPath.row]

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    for (key,value) in rowData {
        cell.productPrice.text = value["merged"][0]["variants"][0]["price"].string
        cell.productName.text = value["merged"][0]["title"].string


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            if let imageString = value["merged"][0]["images"][0]["src"].string {
                let url = NSURL(string: imageString)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    cell.productImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
                    cell.productImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!)
                })
            }
        })


        if let variantData =  value["merged"][0]["variants"].array {
            var sum = 0

            for variant in variantData {
                sum += variant["inventory_quantity"].int!
            }

            if sum <= 0 {
                cell.soldOut.hidden = false

            } else {
                cell.soldOut.hidden = true
            }
        }


    }

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do all of the downloading of the main thread then once the image or image data is available dispatch to the main queue to update the UI. Here you're going in the right direction but you're downloading on the main thread. Change this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            if let imageString = value["merged"][0]["images"][0]["src"].string {
                let url = NSURL(string: imageString)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    cell.productImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
                    cell.productImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(url!)
                })
            }
        })
```

To:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
            if let imageString = value["merged"][0]["images"][0]["src"].string {
                let url = NSURL(string: imageString)
                let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageString)
                let image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    cell.productImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
                    cell.productImage.image = image
                })
            }
        })
```